# Name of an algebraic structure $(A,*,\cdot)$ weaker than semirings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, associativity

I have a set $A$ with two binary operations on it

$(A,*,\cdot)$

STRUCTURE A

- $(A,*)$ is not commutative, is not associative, it has not an identity
- $(A,\cdot)$ is a commutative group
- $(a*b)\cdot c=(a\cdot c)*(b\cdot c)$

STRUCTURE B

- $(A,*)$ is not associative, it has not an identity but it is commmutative
- $(A,\cdot)$ is a commutative group
- $(a*b)\cdot c=(a\cdot c)*(b\cdot c)$

Has one of these structures a name in the literature? Usually, even in the weakest kind of structures with two operations like semi-rings, we have the commutativity and the associativity of the additive operation but the structure A and B are really weaker than anything I've seen: these structure are like Near-Semi-fields with non-associative additive operation.

Comment: If you're fine with artificially adding structure, Structure A can be equivalently described as a $\Bbb Z$-algebra (not necessarily associative) where the action of $\Bbb Z$ is multiplication in the underlying additive group.

Comment: @MikeMiller where I can learn more about this?

Comment: @MikeMiller By the way I don't get how this can help me. Isn't an R-algebra a special kind of R-module...but in my cases I have only two operations on the same set

Comment: I'm not saying anything intelligent here. Any abelian group also has a unique $\Bbb Z$-module structure. So any of your structure A's also have a unique $\Bbb Z$-algebra structure.

Comment: @MikeMiller the problem is not the intelligent things you say...but  the problem is that I don't even know what is a Z-algebra and how can help me with this. When you say "*Structure A can be equivalently described as a Z-algebra (not necessarily associative) where the action of Z is multiplication in the underlying additive group.*" I can't follow you.

Comment: Pick a book that describes what a non associative algebra over a ring is. Profit.